# Check domains existence and get code from the homepage

Tags: dns

I would like to check the existence of all domains of the TLD ".ch".

Then, in the existing ones, I would like to check for a term,

for example `meta name="robots" content="index,follow"`

(could also be others)

Thanks

---

These questions and answers were helpful but didn't answer my question:

(found it with "+check +existence +domains")

[Domain name existence via "dig"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704368/domain-name-existence-via-dig)

[Fast concurrent checking of SOA DNS records for .co.za domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774293/fast-concurrent-checking-of-soa-dns-records-for-co-za-domains)

[Checking domain name availability with DNS records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1780598/checking-domain-name-availability-with-dns-records)